# How to set the alias in webpack in vue-cli4？

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

There is no webpack.base.conf.js file in vue-cli4. How do I set the alias? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create file in root name: vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // path import to example
    const path = require('path')
    // path config.resolve.alias or config.resolve.alias.store
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      'myAlias': 'pathAlias || actionAlias',
      // My  Example
      'social': path.resolve(__dirname, '../Social')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a TypeError: this.alias.entries is not a function

Comment: Tell me what you want to do that I can help you, it's not that simple to access the alias, to access is the way I showed you, making an inheritance. @SamuelZheng

Comment: Thank you for your patience, the problem has been solved, my purpose is to set an alias for the css file for easy access, I solved it by overwriting the configuration file.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I have found another solution:
````    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.resolve.alias
            .set('api', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/api'));
    },
`````